# How to Update the default value of ant design Date Picker when the date/ date state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, datepicker, antd

AntD Version : 5.0

By default, when the page loads it shows the default date. But i'm passing a date which is stored in a state object. After the page loads successfully,when i change the state of the date from one of the component, it does not update the default value of the date picker in all other components. Even i consoled the date, receiving the updated state from the state object, but it does not render the updated state date. How can i solve this problem?

I want that, on the change of date, the default value should be updated in all the date picker components.

Here is my date picker component

```
import { DatePicker, Tabs } from "antd";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "@desktopStyles/common/searchBox.module.css";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

function DepartDateInput({
  classname,
  flightIndex,
  flightInfoObj,
  setFlightInfoObj,
  setFlag,
}) {
  const onDepartDateChange = (date, dateString, flightInd) => {
    setFlightInfoObj((prev) => {
      let oldVal = prev;
      oldVal.departing[flightInd] = dateString;
      return oldVal;
    });
    setFlag((prev) => {
      return !prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classname}>
      <span>{flightInfoObj.departing[flightIndex]}:</span>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={(date, dateString) =>
          onDepartDateChange(date, dateString, flightIndex)
        }
        defaultValue={dayjs(
          String(flightInfoObj.departing[flightIndex]),
          "YYYY-MM-DD"
        )}
      />
     
      <Image
        className={styles.src_ico}
        src={"/images/desktop/src_calander_ico.svg"}
        width={18}
        height={18}
        alt=""
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DepartDateInput;
```

It updated the date in the current component where the date is selected, but not update the default value to the latest value in all other components.

Comment: Please provide debug details.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, have you find any solutions for it ? i tried forceRenedring the component but still not working

Answer (score 0):

The only value prop was missing. After adding the value prop, it starts working fine.

```
< DatePicker
onChange = {
  (date, dateString) =>
  onDepartDateChange(date, dateString, flightIndex)
}
defaultValue = {
  dayjs(
    String(flightInfoObj.departing[flightIndex]),
    "YYYY-MM-DD"
  )
}
value = {
  dayjs(
    String(flightInfoObj.departing[flightIndex]),
    "YYYY-MM-DD"
  )
}
/>
```